# Can I build screen capture with recording features with twilio?

Tags: twilio

I need to build a screen sharing web and mobile app using Twilio with screen recording feature. Use case: A tech support agent help with a software usage a client and this session should be recorded in full (screen, voice & video) and stored on the Twilio cloud. The recordings should be available for streaming. During the session a quality manager should be able to watch live stream of these sessions.

I read the documentations, found Recordings feature, but couldn't find any information regarding recording the screen capture example provided on the tutorials of Twilio.

Is Twilio able to provide all the above features? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Recording through Twilio Video is not currently available. I recommend getting in touch with [support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to register your interest for recording in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I already contacted them, I have to get back to Kurento now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Screen sharing:
       https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/screen-capture-chrome

```
   Recording:
   https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/recordings-resource

    When using our recording service, all audio and video tracks that
    are published to the Room will be recorded and made available for
    download. A quality manager can join the same Room during the
    session and observe silently by not sharing their own 
    microphone/camera.
```

If you haven't already tried our quickstart, I recommend you check it out and let me know if you have any further questions.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/quickstart-sample-apps

All the Best